# Is 'Feedbacker' a real english word?

Tags: vocabulary

As a non native english speaker I stumbled upon the word '**feedbacker**' and I am really confused if this actually is a real English word that people are using. Even some online research could not solve my issue.

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Well, it's [in use](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/feedbacker) but it's new, uncommon and (in my extremely humble opinion) clumsy.

Comment: Thank you. I thought maybe this is not even a word. Very good to know that it really exists

Comment: Just because a word 'exists', in the sense that people use it, that does not mean that you should use it.

Comment: It's a sort of neologism that computer geeks might use.

Comment: It's more compact than 'the source of the feedback'.

Comment: Baseball and hotels have *comebackers*, football and kitchens have *linebackers*, politicians and businessmen have *kickbackers*, Immigration depts. have *sendbackers*, Investors look for *pullbackers*, Airports and media consulting have *pushbackers*, the blogosphere has its *blowbackers*, Wikipedia has *rollbackers*, investing, sports, and (erm) modeling has its *lookbackers*, and animated film has a *Laidbackers* franchise. I suspect we are stuck with it.